# typescript assigning interface key to dynamic prefix key

Tags: typescript

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLADaSgZ2QbwChkTkQ4BbCAfgC5kcwpQBzAbmNIG0BregAzgATIRCEB9ACT5GzECwC+-ALr0AriFExQY5AB8yaigCNo+hk1YdSyXgKgQKAewBuYqTMvylq5Bq06QuYgRqZQ5rJWhAqECE4gjMjAQQC8yADkcMYI6RxxCWDI2hAYqciCIu7SyUp58YnaWNA4tOhNuMhp+AochI3YOFzFpcqdyACMvf3NQ8AlQXB4PBAAnk4waJgDo2mThEA)

I have an interface defined using a dynamic prefix key (`added_${string}`).

but having trouble assigning a key to that property. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

```
interface Filters {
    name?: string;
    [k: `added_${string}`]: undefined | number | string;
    [k: `removed_${string}`]: undefined | number | string;
}
const id = 'abc';
const field = `added_${id}`;
const filters:Filters = {};

filters[field] = 1; // error

filters[field as keyof Filters] = 1; // error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using an `as const` assertion. The feature that makes this possible was implemented in [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40707).

Without using `as const`, the template literal string type will be converted to a `string`.

```
const field = `added_${id}`;
//    ^? field: string
```

And since `Filters` does not have a string index signature, you can not use `field` to index it.

When you use `as const`, this will instead produce another template literal type (or just a literal string type in this case).

```
const id = 'abc';
const field = `added_${id}` as const;
//    ^? const field: "added_abc"
const filters:Filters = {};

filters[field] = 1;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLADaSgZ2QbwChkTkQ4BbCAfgC5kcwpQBzAbmNIG0BregAzgATIRCEB9ACT5GzECwC%20-ALr0AriFExQY5AB8yaigCNo%20hk1YdSyXgKgQKAewBuYqTMvylq5Bq06QuYgRqZQ5rJWhAqEhAhOIIzIwEEAvMgA5HDGCBkc8YlgyNoQGGnIgiLu0ilKyHB4BYz5CUnaWNA4tOgduMjp%20AochO3YOFwlZcr9yACMHEA)